# Object made of nsmanagedobject returns nil in another class

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a `NSMangedObject` Class:

```
@interface INSPHP : NSManagedObject
```

I have made object of this class in another class `ViecontrollerA`, as follows:

```
@interface ViewcontrollerA :UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong) INSPHP* insphp;
@end
```

But when i am trying to put some value in this object as follows:

```
- (void) popOverSelectedValueTo:(id) valueObject {

    if([Str isEqual:@"Test"])
    {
        NSString *v = [[valueObject componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];
        _insphp.rabscd = v;
        NSLog(@"%@",self.insphp);

    }
}
```

It returns nil. Can anybody please explain why is this happening?

Comment: Show where you fetch from Core Data and set the property `insphp`.

Comment: self.insphp= [dictionary safeObjectforKey:@"INSPHP"];

Comment: Please update the question and show how you get or create the instance of insphp. (From to CoreData). Also do some simple debugging and check if `_insphp` is `nil`, which is what I suspect and why I am asking.

Comment: Can you show the retrieval of the data from using CoreData. Maybe there's something wrong to your fetchRequest and co.